# Beta decay of nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics

If I say that during electron capture, the proton gets converted to neutron and for some reason, that neutron has to get converted into proton again by releasing electron that is the $\beta^-$ particle. What will be the difference between the emitted and absorbed electron?

Comment: They are both electrons, which are all alike. But, you seem to have something else in mind - could you clarify the question?

Comment: Make me understand about the difference between beta minus particle and electron in different orbits.

Comment: Note that if Isotope A decays to Isotope B via electron capture, Isotope B will not be unstable to spontaneous decay via $\beta^-$ emissions:  it would have to decay back to Isotope A, which would require an increase in mass.  You'd have to have some external input of energy (and/or nucleons) to get this to occur.

Comment: An electron is an electron - even if you call it $\beta^-$...

Answer (score 2):

1. Nothing. There is no difference between an electron which was just created by a beta decay and another which exists since the big bang. They are absolutely the same.
2. If an electron capture can happen, it means that the state after the capture is energetically more favorable as the state before it. It also means that the reverse reaction won't happen, because there is no energy for that. Note: in both cases also neutrinos are created, also they take away some energy.